# Gem is in gemlist but getting error: "Could not find gem"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

When I try to start my project using `rails s` I have the following error message occur:

```
Could not find gem 'jquery-rails (>= 0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

However, I know I definitely have that gem installed because when I put in the command `gem list` it shows up in my list of gems.

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (3.2.3)
actionpack (3.2.3)
activemodel (3.2.3)
activerecord (3.2.3)
activeresource (3.2.3)
activesupport (3.2.14, 3.2.3)
arel (3.0.2)
bigdecimal (1.1.0)
builder (3.2.2, 3.0.0)
bundler (1.1.5)
c2c_linux_patch_utilities (0.30.0, 0.29.0)
chef (11.6.2)
chef-zero (1.6)
debug_me (0.5.1)
diff-lcs (1.1.3)
erubis (2.7.0)
gelf (1.1.3)
hashie (2.0.5)
highline (1.6.19)
hike (1.2.1)
i18n (0.6.5)
io-console (0.3)
ipaddress (0.8.0)
journey (1.0.3)
jquery-rails (2.0.1)
json (1.7.7, 1.5.5)
knife-lastrun (0.0.4)
mail (2.4.4)
mime-types (1.25)
minitest (3.2.0, 2.5.1)
mixlib-authentication (1.3.0)
mixlib-cli (1.3.0)
mixlib-config (1.1.2)
mixlib-log (1.6.0)
mixlib-shellout (1.2.0)
moneta (0.6.0)
multi_json (1.8.1)
net-ssh (2.7.0)
net-ssh-gateway (1.2.0)
net-ssh-multi (1.2.0, 1.1)
ohai (6.18.0)
polyglot (0.3.3)
pony (1.4, 1.3)
poseidon (0.0.4)
puma (1.6.3)
rack (1.5.2, 1.4.1)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.1)
rails (3.2.3)
railties (3.2.3)
rake (10.1.0, 0.9.2.2)
rdoc (3.12.2, 3.9.5)
rest-client (1.6.7)
rspec (2.12.0)
rspec-core (2.12.2)
rspec-expectations (2.12.1)
rspec-mocks (2.12.2)
rspec_junit_formatter (0.1.6)
ruby-shadow (2.2.0)
sdoc (0.3.20)
simplecov (0.7.1)
simplecov-html (0.7.1)
sprockets (2.3.1, 2.1.2)
systemu (2.5.2, 2.5.1)
thor (0.14.6)
tilt (1.3.3)
treetop (1.4.10)
tzinfo (0.3.31)
xml-simple (1.1.1)
yajl-ruby (1.1.0)
```

I'm not able to use bundler because the connection is blocked at my workplace, but regardless, why is it giving me the error that the gem needs to be installed when it is installed?

---

**Edit:** I used `gem environment gemdir` to see where my path was for my gems and then tried to set the path for where bundlers looked using `bundle config path /installationPath/`, but I'm still having the same errors.

Also it is not a problem with the version numbers of the gems in my Gemfile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bundler messes with the gem load path. `gem list` shows you what's installed on the system, but not necessarily what Bundler will expose to the application. Have you tried `bundle exec rails s` or `bundle list` to see what Bundler is actually exposing?

Comment: Just tried both and got the same error for each: `Could not find gem 'jquery-rails (>= 0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.
`

Comment: It sounds like jquery-rails isn't available in whatever path Bundler is trying to load from. Check your Gemfile.lock; if you didn't run bundle, it may well have a different version locked than what's on your system.

Comment: It doesn't look like `jquery-rails` was constrained to any version in my Gemfile. I think it may be a path error because when I commented out `jquery-rails`, the same issue happened for other gems that i already had installed

Comment: @Chris_Heald I found my installation path with `gem environment gemdir` and set it for bundler using `bundle config path */installationPath/*, but I am still getting the same issue :/